# Duplicate symbol in .framework and .a

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, llvm, mach-o

I am developing a library .a file in Which i am using AFNetworking classes ... This library does also include one .framework which also using the AFNetworking classes (Adding this framework is optional)

Due to this I am getting following errors

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation._responseSerializer in:
    .../KonySDK.framework/KonySDK(AFHTTPRequestOperation.o)
.../Core.a(AFHTTPRequestOperation.o)
```

Options i have already considered is removing AF***.o from one of the file **lipo -thin** and **ar -d -sv** commands

Using [this Link](http://angelolloqui.com/blog/31-How-to-fix-a-Duplicated-Symbols-error-on-binary-files)

But this library is configurable from server and adding that particular .framework is optional.

My question is ... Is there any otherway by which i can resolve this issue ? ALso i can would rather not prefer to remove .m files of AFNetworking from my library source as the entire process of generating library is fully automatic and configurable in many ways

I have also tried to resolve this by removing -all_load from other linker flags but this resulted in crash as categories of some classes are not loaded due to this.

Comment: Not sure if it can solve your problem. Try to use AFNetworking as a library instead of including the source file(*.m) directly.

Comment: It will result in same. my end target is .a file.in which i am adding one optional framework

Comment: To your edit: Add `-ObjC` in other linker flags

Comment: Thanks but i have removed -all_load from other linker ... -ObjC is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the duplicate symbol linker error whenever you have included a binary version of a class. The way to get rid of it is to remove the superfluous object.

For building your library you only need the .h files of AFNetworking because those tell the compiler which classes and methods are available. You do not need to compile the AFNetworking source code because a .a file is essentially a collection of .o files which each contain the compiled versions of .m files.

*Libraries are not linked*

Only apps get linked and therefore need to have the symbols/objects present. i.e. if you provide your library without AFNetworking compiled in, then the developer using it needs to add AFNetworking via library, framework or cocoapod.

Comment: Hi @Cocoanetics ... i removed all .m file of AFNetworking but still getting same duplicate symbols errors